# C++. reinterpret_cast from double to unsigned char*

Tags: c++, char, double, reinterpret-cast

I was having a small play around with C++ today and came across this which I thought was odd, but perhaps more likely due to a misunderstanding by me and lack of pure C coding recently.

What I was looking to do originally was convert a double into an array of unsigned chars. My understanding was that the 64 bits of the double (sizeof(double) is 8) would now be represented as 8 8-bit chars. To do this I was using reinterpret_cast.

So here's some code to convert from double to char array, or at least I thought that's what it was doing. Problem was it was returning 15 from strlen instead of 8, why I'm not sure.

```
double d = 0.3;

unsigned char *c = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*> ( &d );

std::cout << strlen( (char*)c ) << std::endl;
```

So the strlen was my first issue. But then I tried the following and found that it returned 11, 19, 27, 35. The difference between these numbers is 8 so on some level something right is going on. But why does this not return 15, 15, 15, 15, ( as it was returning 15 in the code above ).

```
double d = 0.3;
double d1 = 0.3;
double d2 = 0.3;
double d3 = 0.3;

unsigned char *c_d = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*> ( &d );
unsigned char *c_d1 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*> ( &d1 );
unsigned char *c_d2 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*> ( &d2 );
unsigned char *c_d3 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*> ( &d3 );

std::cout << strlen( (char*)c_d ) << std::endl;
std::cout << strlen( (char*)c_d1 ) << std::endl;
std::cout << strlen( (char*)c_d2 ) << std::endl;
std::cout << strlen( (char*)c_d3 ) << std::endl;
```

So I looked at the addresses of the chars and they are.

```
0x28fec4
0x28fec0
0x28febc
0x28feb8
```

Now this makes sense given that the size of an unsigned char* on my system is 4 bytes, but I thought the correct amount of memory would be allocated from the cast, otherwise it seems like reinterpret_cast is a pretty dangerous thing... Furthermore if I do

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    double d = 0.3;

    unsigned char *c = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*> ( &d );

    std::cout << strlen( (char*)c ) << std::endl;
}
```

This prints 11, 11, 11, 11!

So what is going on here, clearly memory is getting overwritten in places and reinterpret cast is not working as I thought it would (i.e. I'm using it wrong). Having been using strings for so long in C++, sometimes when you go back to raw char arrays, you forget these things.

So I suppose this is a 3 part question.

Why was strlen initially returning 15?
Why did the 4 strlen calls grow in size?
Why did the loop return 11, 11, 11, 11?

Thanks.

Comment: _casting_ does not allocate any storage space.  Using `reinterpret_cast` is basically telling the compiler, "Hey, I know what I'm doing.  Trust me."  Therefore, it's on you to know how much storage space those casts can point to in a valid manner.

Comment: @Chad this sort of answers my question best. As I said in the comment for the selected answer, I was expecting too much from casting. I am aware of the \0 character though, it was really the reinterpret_cast behaviour and what exactly it did that had me a bit confused.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`strlen` works by iterating through the array that it assumes the passed `const char*` points at until it finds a `char` with value 0. This is the null-terminating character that is automatically added to the end of string literals. The bytes that make up the value representation of your `double` do not end with a null character. The `strlen` will just keep going past the end of your `double` object *until* it finds a byte with value 0.

Consider the string literal `"Hello"`. In memory, with an ASCII compatible execution character set, this will be stored as the following bytes (in hexadecimal):

```
48 65 6c 6c 6f 00
```

`strlen` would read through each of them until it found the byte with value `0` and report how many bytes it has seen so far.

The IEEE 754 double precision representation of `0.3` is:

```
3F D3 33 33 33 33 33 33
```

As you can see, there is no byte with value `0`, so `strlen` just won't know when to stop.

Whatever value the function returns is probably just how far it got until it found a 0 in memory, but you've already hit undefined behaviour and so making any guesses about it is pointless.

Comment: I suppose I was expecting too much of reinterpret_cast. I guess in my mind it was sorting out memory and the terminating character for me. Never really crossed my mind that is NOT what reinterpret_cast is supposed to be doing. It does it's job, the rest is up to me.

Comment: @Muckle_ewe `reinterpret_cast` is the most dangerous of casts. It says, "trust me, compiler, I want you to treat this as a different type".

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is your use of `strlen( (char*)c )`, because `strlen` expects a pointer to a null-terminated character string.

It seems like you're expecting some sort of "boundary" between the 8th and 9th byte, since those first 8 bytes were originally a `double`.

That information is lost once you've cast that memory to a `char*`.  It becomes the responsibility of your code to know how many `char`s are valid.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. `sizeof(double)` probably isn't 4.  It's usually 8.  Use the operator instead of a hard-coded assumption.
2. The pointer `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&d)` does not indicate a pointer to a null-terminated "string". `strlen` operates by iterating until it finds a null. You're into undefined behavior there.